# How to recover blockchain.info wallet from 12-word passphrase and password

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I have a 12 word passphrase and password from blockchain.info.  Trouble is that I can't remember the email I used.  Is there a way to retrieve the email with these two pieces of information?

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of 12 word mnemonics from blockchain.info.

They use different word sets and have different meanings depending when they were created.

Pre 2015/2016 12 word seeds cointained your password to log in and were combined from a 50k plus word list. It was called the Legacy mnemonic.

Post 2015/2016 12 word list were combined from a 2048 word list and could be used to restore your public and private keys. These mnemonics are called HD

The blockchain uses separate links to check the validity depending if  you have have the Legacy or HD.

If you enter the list in the HD link and it says word not recognised it is most probably Legacy.

If you get checksum error only then most probably one of your words is misstyped, missspelled, wrong or missing. In that case it is possible to calculated the correct word but it is not an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your 12 words phrase from blockchain.info you can just restore your wallet, then you will use a new email and new password.

To restore your blockchain.info wallet:

1 - Go to: https://login.blockchain.com/#/login

2 - Click on **Need some help?**

3 - Click on **Recover Funds**

4 - Use your 12 word phrase, lowercase, with spaces between each word.

Comment: I have tried that link but it says invalid passphrase.  I know I copied the words down correctly.  Could it be from a wallet that doesn't exist anymore? These words are from back in 2013.

Comment: https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/forgot-password?guid=  My 12 word phrase worked on this website to retrieve my password.  Is there anyway to find out which email I used?

Comment: I am not familiar with this another link, you may need to contact blockchain.info support. But I guess your SEED is compatible with other BIP44/BIP39 bitcoin wallets. You can create an Electrum wallet using your SEED.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? By SEED do you mean the 12 word passphrase?

Comment: Yes, SEED is your 12 word passphrase. 1 - Download the Electrum wallet. 2 - go to create new wallet. 3 - Go with the option to standard wallet. 4 - Go with I already have a SEED. 5 - Click on options and check BIP39 SEED and enter with your SEED.

Comment: Thank you. Should this be able to show me if I have any bitcoins?

Comment: Yes, and then you can spend your Bitcoins from Electrum wallet.

Comment: Above answers are wrong. The blockchain.info 12 words are totally different from the 12 words used after 2015 when HD wallets were introduced and cannot be used with Electrum. Your blockchain.info 12 words were only used to store your password and use a totally different word list.